# MySQL Join plus Count plus Sum

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is complex query, and I was hoping to achieve it one statement, rather than have to juggle array values in PHP.

To achieve the desired output of:

```
User    Jobs    Total
John D. 5       $1245.67
Mary L. 3       $800.56
```

So far, this is the query I have:

```
SELECT
  SUM(job.cost) AS sum,
  COUNT(DISTINCT job.user) as count,
  user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname
FROM      `job`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON job.user = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
```

But the count value is wrong: it's the distinct user, so of course each is going to be wrong. How do I fix this?

TABLE `user`

```
id, name, etc.
```

TABLE `job`

```
id, user, cost
```

With ONE `user` TO MANY `job`

---

UPDATE

This seems to be working right:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(job.cost) AS sum,
  COUNT(1) as count,
  user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname
FROM `job`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON job.user = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
```

Comment: Please describe your table structure with some sample data.

Comment: Or an http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT job.id)` (or any other unique column in `job`

Comment: @Wrikken Actually, COUNT(job.user) did it, posting correct (as far as I know) query.

Comment: SQLFiddle has been around for a looong time :P

Comment: @biziclop I didn't know that existed, that's awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @seq = 0;

SELECT place FROM

(SELECT
  @seq := @seq + 1 AS place
  SUM(job.cost) AS sum,
  COUNT(1) as count,
  user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname
FROM      `job`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON job.user = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) 

AS list
WHERE list.id = 'my_user_id'
```

Comment: How would I determine a specific user's placement in the results without having to loop through them? Any ideas?
----
Actually, I just need to know their placement in regards to number of total jobs

Comment: Descending order, most jobs to least